# Differences in the output data structure between using the R lapply and parSapply functions - how to avoid them?

Tags: r, multithreading, dataframe, data-structures, doparallel

I'm learning Parallel Computing in R. I have managed to go from the single-threaded approach to the multi-threaded approach and my function work both with lapply (single-threaded) and parSapply (multi-threaded) fine. However, I am having trouble getting the same output structure. For lapply, I can just use bind_rows and the result is a simple table ("data.frame" class).

```
results <- lapply(trials, my_function) %>% bind_rows()
results
>  DLikert DNumb DItems    DCcorr    DAlpha    DOmega
>1       2  1000     10 0.1094252 0.5513300 0.5523844
>2       2  1000     10 0.1095712 0.5516687 0.5523042
>3       2  1000     10 0.2091628 0.7256470 0.7258210
>4       2  1000     10 0.2097453 0.7263301 0.7265728
```

But doing the same function multithreaded gives me a class ""matrix" "array"" multidimensional structure.

```
results <- parSapply(clust, trials, my_function) 
results
>        [,1]      [,2]     
>DLikert numeric,2 numeric,2
>DNumb   numeric,2 numeric,2
>DItems  numeric,2 numeric,2
>DCcorr  numeric,2 numeric,2
>DAlpha  numeric,2 numeric,2
>DOmega  numeric,2 numeric,2
```

And when i try to bind_rows:

```
results <- parSapply(clust, trials, my_function) %>% bind_rows()
```

i get error: ! Argument 1 must have names. This is a bit confusing to me, because my_function is exactly the same, so I don't understand why it gives a different output format?

I might try to read the data partially by accessing specific sub-dimensions of this structure, for example like this:

```
s <- as.data.frame(results[,1])
s
  DLikert DNumb DItems    DCcorr    DAlpha    DOmega
1       2  1000     10 0.1094252 0.5513300 0.5523844
2       2  1000     10 0.1095712 0.5516687 0.5523042
```

but maybe someone will show me how to make this multithreaded structure into a simple table form obtained by a single-threaded function? What i miss?

EDIT: thanks to @r2evans solution i made it that way:

```
results <- parLapply(clust, trials, my_function) %>% bind_rows()
```

and that make proper simple structure i needed. It's not entirely clear to me why it works that way, but the list where I can apply the bind_rows function is exactly the structure I needed.

Let me just add that the parSapply function is a bit faster than parLapply, I don't know how much this difference will be felt in big sets.

Comment: You're comparing `lapply` (which never reduces a `list`-reply to a `vector` or `matrix`) with `parSapply`, which knowingly reduces data when reasonable. Have you tried `parLapply`?

Comment: Thank's, parLapply do the work! But I do not fully understand why is this happening? Why these two functions return data differently?

Comment: `sapply` is mostly provided as an interactive function of convenience, its results vary between vector, matrix, and list, based on the structure of each function's return value. This property makes it risky for automated/unsupervised/large-scale operations, preferring either `lapply` (always returns `list`) or `vapply` (provided expected return "shape", fail fast if different). The `par*apply` functions mimic this model. I suggest not using `parSapply` for anything unless you are 100% certain it'll return one value _always_.